# SASS @at-root doesn't compile with ','

Tags: sass

Im' trying to compile some SASS code using `@at-root #{&}` to specify multiple styles to multiple classes sharing the same parent. But the code keep returning some errors.

This is the code I'm trying to compile:

```
header {
    [... exclusive for this class ..]
    .hd {
        @at-root #{&}_left {
            float:left;
            @at-root #{&}-logo,
            @at-root #{&}-search {
                height: $header-height;
                line-height: $header-height;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
            @at-root #{&}-logo {
                [... exclusive for this class ..]
            }
            @at-root #{&}-search {
                [... exclusive for this class ..]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error is happening when i use this `@at-root #{&}-logo,` because of the `,` 
This is the error message:

`"Error: Invalid CSS after \"... .hd_left-logo,\": expected selector, was \"@at-root header...\"`

Is it possible to compile this code using `@at-root`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@at-root` directive requires a valid selector.  Selectors do not end with commas.

```
header {
    [... exclusive for this class ..]
    .hd {
        @at-root #{&}_left {
            float:left;
            @at-root #{&}-logo, #{&}-search {
                height: $header-height;
                line-height: $header-height;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
            @at-root #{&}-logo {
                [... exclusive for this class ..]
            }
            @at-root #{&}-search {
                [... exclusive for this class ..]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. I'm starting using some advanced sass code now, any other tip you could give me?